# Wordpress 404 without trailing slash

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp, http-status-code-404

I know this has probably been answered as it seems a common question but I am having problems getting the solutions around working for me.

I have a wordpress site in a sub directory of another site. when i try and call http://site.com/blog i get redirected and a 404 error but when i call http://site.com/blog/ the page renders as expected.

The solution that keeps coming up seems to be

```
# and does not end with a slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
# then add a trailing slash and redirect
RewriteRule (.*) $1/ [R=301,L]
```

but every time i request the page without the trailing slash i get redirected to http://site.com/app/webroot/blog

the subfolder the blog has been installed is within the webroot of a cakephp app which i think might have something to do with it?

Comment: Just add a `RewriteBase /blog` to the htaccess.

Comment: Thanks, I already had this in the wordpress install root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the [answer](http://www.web7.co/integrate-wordpress-into-cakephp/) to this after more digging around on the net

it was solved for my by adding this to the root .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^blog$ blog/ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the top of your .htaccess file, right under `RewriteEngine On`. I assume the .htaccess file is in the root directory of your site.

```
#if this already exists, skip it, otherwise it should be before any other Rules
RewriteEngine on
#add this line to prevent your directory structure from showing up
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Why not just use `RewriteBase /blog`? Seems easier than having to create another .htaccess file.

Comment: @Gerben I meant add `RewriteBase /` to the existing htaccess file which I assume is in the root directory. Let me know which part of my answer suggested otherwise and I will correct.  Thanks

Comment: He had wordpress installed in `/blog/` so I assumed the htaccess was located in `/blog`